# AngularJS ng-attr not working when used with a tag with a dash

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to generate a JS Chart with a value from a $scope but the value does not get updated in that specific tag because it has a dash in it, it works perfectly when I tested it in the div above to replace the width's value of 100 with the $scope and it works but just not with this specific tag. Any ideas?

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
    <div>
        <p>Option1</p>
        <div class="">
            <div class="progress progress_sm" style="width: 100%;">
                <div class="progress-bar bg-green" role="progressbar" ng-attr-data-transitiongoal="{{total | number:0}}"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the code from the controller, the server code for the route (for pulling data from MongoDB) works perfectly because I was able to pull the data and I have been able to use console.log() to print in the route as well:

**Script**

```
function HomeCtrl($scope, $http, $filter) {
    $scope.total = 0;
    var refresh = function() {
        $http.get("/homelist").success(function(response) {
            $scope.homelist = response;
            var homelista = $scope.homelist;
            for (var i = 0; i < homelista.length; i++) {
                var donedeals = homelista[i];
                $scope.total += (Number(donedeals.hgtgt));
            }
        };
        refresh();
    }
}
```

More importantly I am able to use the data in the js file with other html tags, so the server or the controller is not the problem at all but it is either a bug with Angular or something I am missing with the html tag.

Comment: Can you please provide the code that attemps to use it?

Comment: Hi Andres, please find the code attached. Thanks.

Comment: Just for someone who has a similar issue, the problem for me was that I was plugging in the value for a JS Chart which was initiating another JS file, so this was not getting called again after the data was getting loaded into the controller, so I took the code from the JS Chart file and included it into my controller and plugged the value directly to the chart and it worked just fine.